# How to add apache tomcat server in services.msc?

Tags: java, tomcat, service, windows-services

I am installing tomcat in my machine.But I want to add tomcat service in services.msc.
How to add Tomcat service in services.msc?

I had already run the service.bat file in Apache Tomcat > bin > service.bat but still not seen in services.msc

Comment: Does that service.bat file log out anywhere? So that you can see if the setting up of the service has failed?